# How to append React Component at html object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement drag&drop thing. 
With, `onDragOver` find the html object and setstate this object ( ex) div )

and when I `ondrop`, I want to append some React Component ( ex) class Button extends Component ) after the state.

I find `insertAdjecentHtml` or `replacewith`. but when I use this, it printed like [object Object]
so there's any method for this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you could have your render function return slightly different html if a condition is met based on the components state.

for example:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    wasDragged: false;
  }
}
onDragStatusChange(){
  //what triggers this is up to you to determine.
  this.setState({
    wasDragged: true
  })
  // also consider setting it back to false under some condition
}
render() {
   <div>
   <p> heres the rest of our form!</p>
     {if(this.state.wasDragged) {
        <input type='button' value='click me' />
     }}
   </div>
   }
}
```